# Is there a command line tool to run carbonite's "back this up"?

Tags: windows, command-line, carbonite

Is there some way to say "Back this up" to Carbonite on the command line on Windows?  I know I can do it through explorer and the right click window, but I'm bit of a scripting fiend.

I'm only trying to automate things I can already back up if I went through the process manually.  Also, I know there are other backup options out there, but Carbonite is what I've got and am sticking with for now.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: No, there isn't any.**

I believe there is no official CLI for it so I looked for script automation.

[image: Context Menu]

What I found is that the main menu item is accessible but not the submenu item.

- [Select a specific menu item from a Windows context (right-click) menu using VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437161/select-a-specific-menu-item-from-a-windows-context-right-click-menu-using-vbsc)
- [Use PowerShell to Work with Windows Explorer](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/26/use-powershell-to-work-with-windows-explorer)
- [ShellFolderItem.InvokeVerbEx method (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There is a chance that when a submenu item is clicked, it actually calls an executable with command line parameters which can be inspected in the Windows Task Manager or Process Explorer. If this is not the case, you may as well give up unless you are competent in coding with the Windows API.

- [How to access Windows shell context menu items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777121/how-to-access-windows-shell-context-menu-items)
- [How to Get ShellNew sub menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052139/how-to-get-shellnew-sub-menu-items)